Records closest to the time
I need to get 2 records for each date that have time closest to some defined time
For example, this is table (real table has more data)
CREATE TABLE t1 (time DATE, some_data NUMBER);

And that table will have records like this
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(TO_DATE('1.1.2024 08:08:08', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 1);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(TO_DATE('1.1.2024 10:10:10', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 2);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(TO_DATE('1.1.2024 15:15:15', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 3);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(TO_DATE('1.1.2024 20:20:20', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 4);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(TO_DATE('2.1.2024 09:09:09', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 5);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(TO_DATE('2.1.2024 12:12:12', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 6);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(TO_DATE('2.1.2024 16:16:16', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 7);

I would like to get 2 records for each date, first one closest to 8 and second closest to 20 hours. In this example result data would be
1.1.2024 08:08:08       1
1.1.2024 20:20:20       4
2.1.2024 09:09:09       5
2.1.2024 16:16:16       7

I tried do this using subqueries, but since my real usage has complex query (with joins, subselects and so on) I got lost in it rather quick.
Is there any good and clean way to accomplish this?
Thank you in advance

You could work out the difference between each time and 08:00 and 20:00 on the same day:
trunc(t1.time) + interval '8' hour - time
trunc(t1.time) + interval '20' hour - time

which could be positive or negative, so then get the absolute value:
abs(trunc(t1.time) + interval '8' hour - time)
abs(trunc(t1.time) + interval '20' hour - time)

then rank those in order for each day:
rank() over (partition by trunc(time)
  order by abs(trunc(t1.time) + interval '8' hour - time))
rank() over (partition by trunc(time)
  order by abs(trunc(t1.time) + interval '20' hour - time))

which gives you:
select t1.time, t1.some_data,
  rank() over (partition by trunc(time)
    order by abs(trunc(t1.time) + interval '8' hour - time)) as rnk8,
  rank() over (partition by trunc(time)
    order by abs(trunc(t1.time) + interval '20' hour - time)) as rnk20
from t1




TIME
SOME_DATA
RNK8
RNK20




2024-01-01 08:08:08
1
1
4


2024-01-01 10:10:10
2
2
3


2024-01-01 15:15:15
3
3
2


2024-01-01 20:20:20
4
4
1


2024-01-02 09:09:09
5
1
3


2024-01-02 12:12:12
6
2
2


2024-01-02 16:16:16
7
3
1



and finally select only those rows that rank highest:
select time, some_data
from (
  select t1.time, t1.some_data,
    rank() over (partition by trunc(time)
      order by abs(trunc(t1.time) + interval '8' hour - time)) as rnk8,
    rank() over (partition by trunc(time)
      order by abs(trunc(t1.time) + interval '20' hour - time)) as rnk20
  from t1
)
where rnk8 = 1
or rnk20 = 1
order by time




TIME
SOME_DATA




2024-01-01 08:08:08
1


2024-01-01 20:20:20
4


2024-01-02 09:09:09
5


2024-01-02 16:16:16
7



fiddle
If you have two rows with the same (absolute) difference then you will see both, because rank() will give the same answer. If you don't want that to happen then you will need to decide how to break ties, by adding ordering conditions (e.g. the non-abs difference, then maybe some other column). Or you could use dense_rank() or row_number(), which would both only evaluate to 1 for a single row - but which of the rows would be returned would be indeterminate. It's better to be explicit to get consistent results.

If you want to keep it simple, you can do it without interval type maths. Here's how to do it easy way:
select dt, time, some_data
  from (select q.*, rank() over(partition by q.dt, q.target_time order by q.dist asc) rnk
          from (select 8 / 24 target_time
                      ,abs(time - trunc(time) - 8 / 24) dist
                      ,trunc(time) dt
                      ,time
                      ,some_data
                  from t1
                union all
                select 20 / 24 target_time
                      ,abs(time - trunc(time) - 20 / 24) dist
                      ,trunc(time) dt
                      ,time
                      ,some_data
                  from t1) q)
 where rnk = 1
 order by dt, time;

